# What is this extremely fast growing plant?

Tags: identification, asparagus

I noticed this plant last week. It started off with as a little stub, and grew straight up without branching and then at about 3 feet, created this branched structure. In about 2 weeks time, it grew from nothing to 6 feet now.

Can someone tell me what plant this is please? Should I kill it or let it be?

[image: Plant Id]

Edit: Country/Region - UK/London

Comment: Looks like asparagus to me

Comment: Did it look like [these](http://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/7810/plants-like-chimney-sprouting-in-iran-what-are-they) when it first sprouted?

Comment: @waxeagle - Thank you. I have added a little more in the description.

Thank you everybody. I didn't realise asparagus grows this quickly and to these heights!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is [garden asparagus.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asparagus) The female plants produce berries, which birds eat. The seeds are distributed through the droppings. That plant looks like a two to three year old one. If you want to keep it (many people do), you may want to move it to an area with more space. These things *can* get up to eight feet tall and wide in really good conditions, but even a normally sized plant (6 1/2' tall and wide) needs a good bit of room. I usually weed these out as seedlings before they get too established. I keep a small (75') row near the house so I have to pull a lot of seedlings in the landscaped beds.
[image]

Answer (score 4):

It looks like [an asparagus shoot](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asparagus) to me.  Did the little stub look like [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File%3aAsparagus_Tip.jpg) before it shot up?  If so, I think we can say pretty confidently that that's what it is.

Are there other shoots coming from the base, or just this one?

Comment: There is another shoot coming from near the base. There is another shoot (that's grown to 4 feet) about 10 feet away.